# Java - How can i do a read methode without skipping a line because of the other readline method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I am trying to setup a highscore system to sort the scores from a file and seperate the names from the numbers. But when I try to use readline twice it skips 1 line because of the other readline method. Can somebody help me please, it's for school!

Example of the file:

kevin:50 dustin:31 nobody:71 imax:23

Here is the code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String name="";
    try (BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res/highscore.txt"))){
        while (br.ready()){
            result.add(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().split(":")[1]));
            name = br.readLine().split(";")[0];
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        Collections.sort(result);
        Collections.reverse(result);
        for (Integer integer : result) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Would you mind provide a sample data to visualize the problem?

Comment: If you wanted to obtain two data items from one line, then store the result of `readLine` in a **variable** and parse the data from that variable.

Comment: Include your `highscore.txt` file in the question please.

Comment: Your usage of `BufferedReader.ready()` is not valid here. It is not a test for end of stream. You should be testing for `readLine()` returning null.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of explanation on @thewho69's answer.

You have fallen into the trap of side-effects. A method might not only do what its name would intuitively suggest. In this example, the `readLine()` method does not only read the upcoming line, but also sets the cursor position to the beginning of the next line.

This makes the `readLine` method not idempotent, which means that calling the method twice with the same parameters (in this case none) will not necessarily return the same output.

In order not to fall into this trap, you have to find a way to use the current one line multiple times, while calling the `br.readLine()` method only once - thus setting the cursor position only once in an iteration, which is desirable in this case. A good solution to this problem is what @thewho69 suggested ~20mins ago.

Answer (score 1):

Simply store each line in a variable:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String name="";
    try (BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res/highscore.txt"))){
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            result.add(Integer.parseInt(line.split(":")[1]));
            name = line.split(";")[0];
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        Collections.sort(result);
        Collections.reverse(result);
        for (Integer integer : result) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```